# Как ограничить подключение по ssh пользователям в jenkins?

Tags: ssh, jenkins

Как ограничить подключение по ssh из jenkins пользователю?
Необходимо, чтобы один проект был доступен всем. В то же время, разграничить пользователям(в зависимости от ролей) подключение до определенных хостов.
Возможно ли сделать это с помощью jenkins или другого инструментария?

Comment: вероятно, сначала вам надо узнать ответ на совсем другой вопрос: это вообще к *jenkins* имеет хоть малейшее отношение?

Comment: имеет отношение. Пользователь будет запускать скрипты на удаленном хосте по ssh через jenkins. Нужно, чтобы у каждого пользователя был свой пул разрешенных хостов для выполнения ssh-команд

Comment: Ну как, вы нашли какое-нибудь решение?

Answer (score 0):

В схеме без участия Jenkins этот вопрос решается довольно просто:

- Каждый пользователь имеет имя и SSH-ключ.
- На каждом хосте создана учетная запись с этим именем и в `/home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys` добавлена публичная часть ключа тех пользователей, которым можно заходить на этот хост. Либо на крайний случай есть один на всех пользователь и у него в `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` все публичные ключи.

С Jenkins эта схема ломается: на нем просто нет учетных записей на каждого пользователя. Все задачи выполняются под пользователем `jenkins` (про точное имя рискую соврать, перепроверьте). Поэтому для различения пользователей нам в любом случае понадобится получить имя пользователя, запустившего сборку, непосредственно в коде сборки. Кажется, по умолчанию такой переменной окружения нет, но ее добавляет, например, плагин [Build User Vars](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin). С ним у нас есть `BUILD_USER_ID`. Дальше приходят на ум такие варианты решения. Наверняка есть что-то лучше, возможно есть специальный плагин — так что не воспринимайте это как руководство или гарантию надежности, безопасности или чего угодно другого.

1. Решение через SSH

   Можно положить приватные ключи всех пользователей где-то на Jenkins, а при выполнении задач обращаться к ним:

   ```
   ssh ${BUILD_USER_ID}@hostname -i path/to/${BUILD_USER_ID}/id_rsa ...

   ansible-playbook --private-key=path/to/${BUILD_USER_ID}/id_rsa -u ${{BUILD_USER_ID}} ...
   ```

   Тут есть существенный недостаток: вы будете хранить приватные ключи на Jenkins, который безопасностью не отличается. Может быть довольно просто получить доступ к ним из какой-нибудь другой задачи.
2. Программное решение

   Можно написать программу на любом языке, в которой получить переменную окружения `BUILD_USER_ID`, сверить ее со списком хостов и продолжить либо прервать работу. Списки соответствия хостов и пользователей хранить в репозитории git с публичным доступом на чтение, но запись (push) только для избранных.

   Ограничение — возможность управлять доступом только из кода задачи Jenkins. Фактический доступ пользователей до конкретного хоста по SSH никак не будет соотноситься с доступом через Jenkins. Но это может быть и преимуществом.
3. Вообще без Jenkins

   Если пользователи достаточно компетентны, то для запуска скриптов вообще не нужен Jenkins. Достаточно обычной схемы с управлением доступом по ключам, запуск скриптов завернуть в ansible или хотя бы в локальные shell-скрипты, которые потом будут запускаться по `./name.sh`. Если вы выбрали ansible и хотите избавить пользователей даже от написания длинных строк, можно обернуть типовые задачи в Make или python-invoke. Я делаю как-то так:

   ```
   @task
   def deploy(ctx, *hostnames):
       # в Ansible хосты перечисляются через ':'
       ansible_limit = ':'.join(hostnames)
       ctx.run('ansible-playbook deploy.yml -i hosts -l {}'.format(ansible_limit))
   ```

Comment: Пользователи разные, у них есть свои учетные данные к jenkins. Ключ для удаленного доступа к хосту по ssh один для всех хостов. В этом случае, у меня должно быть ограничение по разрешенным хостам для пользователей jenkins'а(Иванова, Петрова, etc)